# Specifying font for a row in pdf table C#

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

```
iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);

iTextSharp.text.Font redfont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.RED);

//here I am adding that font for values in a pdf table
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                if((r[3])=="0")------------------------------------------//
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                else
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), redfont));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));


            }
        } document.Add(table);
```

When I am writing the condition of `if((r[3])=="0")`, it was giving the redfont even if the value of `r[3]` is equal to "0". Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that r[3] is not of a type String. What you have to do is:

```
if(r[3].ToString()=="0")
```